# Constrain an associated type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, associated-types

A simplified version of my code which shows the problem:

```
protocol Transformer {
    typealias Input
    typealias Output

    func transform(s: Input) -> Output
}

protocol InputType {}
protocol OutputType {}

extension Int: OutputType {}
extension String: InputType {}

struct StringToInt: Transformer {
    typealias Input = String
    typealias Output = Int

    func transform(s: Input) -> Output {
        return s.characters.count
    }
}

typealias Transform = InputType -> OutputType

func convert<T: Transformer where T.Input == InputType, T.Output == OutputType>
    (transformer: T) -> Transform {
    return transformer.transform
}

convert(StringToInt()) // error: Cannot invoke 'convert' with an argument list of type '(StringToInt)'
```

I'm guessing that the error occurs because the compiler cannot reach into `StringToInt` and verify that `Input` and `Output` indeed conform to `InputType` and `OutputType` respectively.

For me, the best way to solve this would be to constrain the associated types directly in the protocol. It would be more expressive and the compiler would have more information. But simply doing `typealias Input: InputType` doesn't work.

Is there any way to constrain an associated type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create extension for `Transformer` protocol

```
extension Transformer where Input: InputType, Output: OutputType {
    func convert() -> Input -> Output {
        return transform
    }
}
```

Now you can call `convert` method on `StringToInt` instance.

```
StringToInt().convert()
```

But for other type that doesn't have `Input` and `Output` adopting `InputType` and `OutputType` it won't compile

```
struct DoubleToFloat: Transformer {
    func transform(s: Double) -> Float {
        return Float(s)
    }
}

DoubleToFloat().convert() // compiler error
```

Comment: But if you replace the return type of `convert()` to be `InputType -> OutputType` instead of `Input -> Output` it doesn't work anymore. Why?

Comment: Because `transform` is `Input -> Output` not `InputType -> OutputType`. You can't treat protocols as regular types in Swift most of the time. However that is not the reason for the error here. Look at this picture for detail. http://milen.me/images/writings/swift-generic-protocols/swift-protocols-two-worlds.png

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `Transform` alias usage, add generics for the input and the output types and map those to `Transformer`, and you'll get a working code for `StringToInt` and for other transformers that you write:

```
func convert<T: Transformer, I, O where T.Input == I, T.Output == O>
    (transformer: T) ->  I -> O {
        return transformer.transform
}

convert(StringToInt())
```

BTW, you don't need to specify the type aliases for `StringToInt`, the compiler is able to infer those from the function definition, if you specify the actual types:

```
struct StringToInt: Transformer {

    func transform(s: String) -> Int {
        return s.characters.count
    }
}
```